# python 3.6.6 multiprocessing under ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ubuntu-18.04, amd-processor

I have just gotten a spanking new EPYC server, running Ubuntu 18.04, with 48 cores, and imagine my dismay when I found that using the python (3.6.6) multiprocessing module and then mapping a function over a list randomly drops list elements on the floor (meaning, my list, which is a list of dates and has length 234, sometimes returns a result of length 234, sometimes of length 176, sometimes of length 11...) The same code works fine under Ubuntu 16.04 and the exact same python version on a Xeon server.

Is this a known problem? If so, is the OS or the CPU or the Python responsible?

Comment: Can you show us some of the code you're testing with?

Comment: @Gigaflop It's fairly involved - I will try to generate the minimal example which fails. I was hoping someone would see the question and say, yeah! I had a problem like that :)

Comment: Such an unfixed bug in Python multiprocessing is possible, but highly unlikely, even if it works fine with earlier software. To get useful heplp here, make your reproducer code minimal, and add it to your question.